# Data locality in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, bigdata, distributed-computing, spark-streaming

Recently I've been doing performance tests on Spark Streaming. I ran a receiver on one of the 6 slaves and submitted a simple Word Count application to the cluster(actually I know this configuration is not proper in practice,just a simple test).I analyzed the scheduling log and found that nearly 88% of tasks are scheduled to the node where receiver ran on and the locality are always PROCESS_LOCAL and the CPU utilization is very high. Why does not Spark Streaming  distribute data across the cluster and make full use of cluster? I've read official guide and it does not explain in detail, especially in Spark Streaming. Will it copy stream data to another node with free CPU and start new task on it when a task is on a node with busy CPU? If so, how can we explain the former case?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the stream `receiver` just on one of the 6 nodes, all the received data are processed on this node (that is the **data locality**).

Data are not distributed across other nodes by default. If you need the input stream to be repartitioned (balanced across cluster) before further processing, you can use

`inputStream.repartition(<number of partitions>)`

This distributes the received batches of data across the specified number of machines in the cluster before further processing.

You can read more about level of parallelism in Spark documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning

Comment: I did repartition test and the delay of Streaming seems to be unimproved, even bigger than before. Experiments are done in a virtual cluster of 6 nodes hosted on two physical servers.

Comment: What about starting more than one receiver? Has the CPU utilization changed in the cluster? Not it should be more less balanced across all nodes.

Comment: The CPU utilization has changed in the virtual cluster with repartition. It seems to be more balanced across all nodes, but the delay is unimproved significantly. I'm not sure what causes this, repartition leads more load to the node where receiver runs on , or more network transferring?

Comment: Yes, all the data are transferred via network from the receiving node to all other nodes. That may take some time. And when the example program is just simple *word count*, then it may take more time then counting itself. But it depends.